# Let $ X\sim \exp(\lambda) $ and let $ (U|X=k) \sim U[x-1,x+1] $ for $ x\ge 0 $. Why $ P(X=k) \ne 0 $?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Iv'e encountered the following definition:

> $X\sim \exp(\lambda)$ and let $(U|X=x) \sim \mathcal U[x-1,x+1]$ for $x\geq 0$.

Now I know that since $X$ is continuous, $P(X=x)=0$ for any $x$. So how can we even discuss $(U|X=x)$?

Comment: I don't know where you have encountered that, but I hope you have encountered the definition of conditional distribution before that. So do you know the definition of conditional distribution?

Comment: @Shashi yes I do but I don't know how to apply that here, If $P(X=x)=0$ how does it even possible to handle?

Comment: Informally you may think of $U | \, X = x$ as $U | \, X \in (x - dx, x + dx)$. This is not a rigorous way of explaining but it should help your intuition.

Comment: The conditional density of $(U|X=x) $ is simply $$\frac{f_{U, X} (u, x) } {f_X(x)} $$ So there is nowhere where you encounter any troubles  with the fact that $P(X=x) =0$. Is this clear?

Comment: @Shashi yes, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X|Y)$ can be written as $f(Y)$ for some measurable function  $f: \mathbb  R \to \mathbb  R$ and $E(X|Y=x)$ is the notation used for the function $f(x)$.